# Vertical viewpager with vertical scrollview

Tags: android, android-viewpager, scrollview

I'm trying to use a vertical scrollview in conjunction with a vertical viewpager (see https://github.com/kaelaela/VerticalViewPager), and I'm not sure how to tackle it.

Essentially, I have two fragments, one lower fragment (the one that is defaulted to when the activity starts) which contains a full-screen scrollview, and one upper fragment which I want to reach when the user is at the top of the lower fragment's scrollview and **continues** to pull down. If anyone has used Facebook messenger, it's similar to their functionality where if you continue to scroll down on their chats page, the camera is started.

Right now, the scrollview blocks the action of opening the second fragment unless i pull down from a very specific angle.

I've considered implementing something using the `OnOverScroll` method of the scrollview (if Y scroll position is 0), but I feel that would lead to a bad UX because even the slightest overscroll would pull down a whole new fragment.

If anyone has any ideas, I'd be really grateful.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by wrapping my scrollview in a SwipeRefreshLayout. Here are the steps, to help anyone that runs into this issue in the future:

After wrapping your scrollview in the SwipeRefreshLayout, set the layout to transparent in code using `mySwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors`.

Then use

```
mySwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
                new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRefresh() {
                        // do your pull-down task here
                    }
                });
```

to listen for when the user pulls down their scrollview from the top.

Slightly hacky solution but avoids writing custom class extensions that could introduce bugs and uses an existing feature to pretty nicely achieve the desired outcome.